# How to send out two request at the same time with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, klein-mvc

So I was following a guide at http://tavendo.com/blog/post/going-asynchronous-from-flask-to-twisted-klein/ to create an asynchronous web service.

in my code, I had a function that will send out the request like

```
def query(text):
    resp = yield treq.get("http://api.Iwanttoquery")
    content = yield treq.content(resp)
    returnValue(content)

@inlineCallbacks
def caller():
    output1 = yield query("one")
    output2 = yield query("two")
```

Since each query to the api usually take about 3 seconds, with my current code the result comes back after 6 seconds. I wonder is there a way to send out two queries at the same time so after 3 seconds I can get the content of both output1 and output2? Thanks.

Comment: you could use threads or find a way to merge the queries into one query

Comment: Your "issue" is that you're using ``inlineCallbacks`` which (for lack of better words) acts like synchronous code.  So basically ``output1`` has to yield a value before it can move on to ``output2``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use a [`DeferredList`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#deferredlist) instead of `inlineCallbacks`.  Basically you provide a list of deferreds and after each one completes, a final callback with the results of all the deferreds is executed.

```
import treq
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor

def query(text):
    get = treq.get('http://google.com')
    get.addCallback(treq.content)
    return get

output1 = query('one')
output2 = query('two')

final = defer.DeferredList([output1, output2])  # wait for both queries to finish
final.addCallback(print)    # print the results from all the queries in the list

reactor.run()
```

Each `query()` function will execute requests concurrently then return a `Deferred`.  This happens almost immediately, so basically `output1` and `output2` are executing at the same time.  Then you append the deferreds (ie. `output1` and `output2`) inside a `list` and pass it in `DeferredList`, which itself returns a `Deferred`.  Finally, you add a callback to the `DeferredList` to do something with the results (in this case I just print them).  This is all done without the use of threads, which is the best part in my opinion!  Hope this makes sense and please comment if it doesn't.

## PS

If you need further help with Klein, I'm working on revamping the documentation here https://github.com/notoriousno/klein-basics (hopefully I'll make a blog post one of these days).  Please take a look at some of the docs (the files with `.rst`).  My shameless plug is now concluded :D